Стриминг tty docker-контейнера
Мне нужно реализовать функционал стриминга терминала docker контейнера, для этого я использовал  ContainerLogs и построчно собирал логи из контейнера.
Однако в случае использования контейнером tty у меня возникают проблемы. В таком случае, я получаю строки логов с escape кодами (отчистка терминала, строки и тд). У меня нет проблемы отобразить это в нормальном виде, однако это сложно назвать стримингом терминала контейнера с tty.
К терминалу контейнера, не используя docker-api, можно подключится с помощью docker attach, но как потом стримить это, мне тоже не ясно
Хотелось бы как-то стримить своеобразный "экран терминала" контейнера, матрицу символов, однако нигде не могу найти информации по этому поводу.

Как вариант прикрепить внешнее устройство на которое будет выводиться поток из терминала (типа /dev/usbserialXXX как в примере), и запускать приложение внутри контейнера с редиректом вывода на это устройство. Вероятно следует посмотреть в сторону client.ContainerAttach
